# No visible space between words in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, typesetting

I'm using an Arabic font called JF Flat. Everything was fine but when I started on a new project the space between the letters does not show and when I press space nothing happens.

[image]

I wrote two spaces between those words but they are not visible.

Comment: when you use another font, what happens?

Comment: the problem isn't with the illustrator or the font .. when i open a new document or a window the problem is solved ..

but with that window the problem is the same with all the fonts

Comment: Seems unlikely but if you open the justification settings from the paragraph panel is "word spacing" set to "0%"?

Answer (score 2):

Go into **Paragraph - Justification settings**
change ***Minimum*** and ***Desired*** word spacing to 100%

Answer (score 1):

Check your "Single Word Justification"setting
Steps:
When in edit mode select "paragraph" from your tool bar.
Select the button at the top right in the dialogue box (3 rows of a dot & a line).
Select "Justification"
Select "Single Word Justification"  If this shows "fully Justify" change to one of the align options.